# SQL Query to get a unique seqence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I  have following data:

```
Txn Nmbr    Item ID     Desc
4           1111        Test 1
6           2222        Test 2
6           3333        Test 3
7           4444        Test 4
7           5555        Test 5
7           6666        Test 6
```

I want all above data with ONE MORE COLUMN which is unique sequence number for each 'Txn Nmbr'. So, output required is,

```
Txn Nmbr    Item ID     Desc        Unique Txn
4           1111        Test 1      1
6           2222        Test 2      2
6           3333        Test 3      2
7           4444        Test 4      3
7           5555        Test 5      3
7           6666        Test 6      3
```

Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tell me: How is your `Unique Txn` semantically different from your `Txn Nmbr`?

Comment: Hello @Anders R. Bystrup: Thanks for the response. Unique Txn is basically a unique sequence number for each transaction, so that at the end I can have the total number of transactions.

Comment: But you could get the same count by  counting `select unique TxnNmbr`...?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @table as TABLE(TxnNmbr INT, ItemID INT, Descr NVARCHAR(50))

insert into @table values (4, 1111, 'Test1')
insert into @table values (6, 2222, 'Test2')
insert into @table values (6, 3333, 'Test3')
insert into @table values (7, 4444, 'Test4')
insert into @table values (7, 5555, 'Test5')
insert into @table values (7, 6666, 'Test6')

SELECT
   *,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [TxnNmbr]) AS [Unique Txn]
FROM @table
```

Comment: That will not "restart" the numbering for each txn_number, because the partition by is missing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thank you so much for the script. However as you rightly said, it gets restarted the number for each txn nmbr. How can I avoid this? Please help!

Comment: @user1839815 I din't get you, please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at TSQL `RANK` - [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
select txn_number, 
       item_id, 
       desc, 
       row_number() over (partition by txn_number order by item_id) as unique_txn
from the_table
```

Comment: Numbers are still getting restarted. Output now I am getting is,                                                Txn Nmbr    Item ID     Desc        Unique Txn
4           1111        Test 1      1
6           2222        Test 2      1
6           3333        Test 3      2
7           4444        Test 4      1
7           5555        Test 5      2
7           6666        Test 6      3

Comment: @user1839815: but your example shows that the "unique" number **is** restarted for every txn number. Your example doesn't match your question then. Do you want a unique number across the **whole** result? In that case simply remove the `partition by` part.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFiddleExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/305da/2)**

```
SELECT
t1.*,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM tbl t2
 WHERE t1.[Txn Nmbr] = t2.[Txn Nmbr]) as [Unique Txn]
FROM tbl t1
```

Result:

```
| TXN NMBR | ITEM ID |   DESC | UNIQUE TXN |
--------------------------------------------
|        4 |    1111 | Test 1 |          1 |
|        6 |    2222 | Test 2 |          2 |
|        6 |    3333 | Test 3 |          2 |
|        7 |    4444 | Test 4 |          3 |
|        7 |    5555 | Test 5 |          3 |
|        7 |    6666 | Test 6 |          3 |
```